# Making IFs ELSEIFs & ANDs work

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the below AMPscript that is throwing this error:

> Multiple logical conditions for a script `IF/ELSEIF` exist but the required logical `AND` or `OR` operator joining a secondary condition is missing. 
>   Script: `(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) != "" AND (@Raise_Late_Communication__c) == "S"`

I'm stumped.

```
%%[
SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = ""
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = ""
SET @Raise_Late_Communication__c =""

if rowcount(@rows) > 1 then 

SET @row = row(@rows,1)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")
SET @Raise_Late_Communication__c = field(@row,"Raise_Late_Communication__c")

endif

IF (@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) != "" AND (@Raise_Late_Communication__c) == "S" THEN
 You have qualified for the following scholarships:

Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%
Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###"))=%%
Scholarship Title: Scholarship
Scholarship Amount: $

ELSEIF

 (@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) == "" AND (@Raise_Late_Communication__c) == "S" THEN

You have qualified for the following scholarship:

Scholarship Title: Scholarship
Scholarship Amount: $

ELSEIF

 (@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) != "" AND (@Raise_Late_Communication__c) != "S" THEN

You have qualified for the following scholarship:

Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%
Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###"))=%%
ELSEIF
(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) == "" AND (@Raise_Late_Communication__c) != "S" THEN

ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to stop and start your AMPscript blocks if you're going to output HTML and inline AMPscript.

You can also utilize the [**empty**](https://ampscript.guide/empty) (with/without the *not* operator) function in your conditionals.  It's a little shorter.

```html
%%[

    SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey)
    SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = ""
    SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = ""
    SET @Raise_Late_Communication__c =""

    if rowcount(@rows) > 1 then 

        SET @row = row(@rows,1)
        SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
        SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")
        SET @Raise_Late_Communication__c = field(@row,"Raise_Late_Communication__c")

    endif

]%%

%%[ IF not empty(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND @Raise_Late_Communication__c == "S" THEN ]%%

    You have qualified for the following scholarships:
    Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%
    Scholarship Amount: $%%=FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###")=%%
    Scholarship Title: Scholarship
    Scholarship Amount: $

%%[ ELSEIF empty(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND @Raise_Late_Communication__c == "S" THEN ]%%

    You have qualified for the following scholarship:

    Scholarship Title: Scholarship
    Scholarship Amount: $

%%[ ELSEIF not empty(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND @Raise_Late_Communication__c != "S" THEN ]%%

    You have qualified for the following scholarship:

    Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%
    Scholarship Amount: $%%=FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###")=%%

%%[ ELSEIF empty(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND @Raise_Late_Communication__c != "S" THEN ]%%


%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```